# How can I swap the form values of table row1 by the form values of table row2 without changing the table rows using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, dom-traversal

I am trying to swap the form values in row1 with the form values of row2 without swapping the rows. Can someone show me away to achieve this in pure Javascript, vanilla JS, or jQuery. I made the table rows shorter with just two rows, but the actual table consists of 17 rows. Please look very closely at the ids and form values in the third example.

When the UP or DOWN button is not click, the table looks like this in simple form:

```
   <form id="menuitems">
    <table class="toolbaritems">
       <tbody class="sortable">
       <tr id="row1">
          <td><button class="up_arrow">UP</button></td>
          <td><input value="1></td>
          <td><select><option="1" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="1a" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><img id="img1"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="row2">
          <td><button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button></td>
          <td><input value="2"></td>
          <td><select><option="2" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="2a" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><img id="img2"></td>
       </tr>
      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="SAVE"></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

This the code currently - When the UP or DOWN buttons are clicked the table looks like this:

```
   <form id="menuitems">
    <table class="toolbaritems">
       <tbody class="sortable">
       <tr id="row2">
          <td><button class="up_arrow">UP</button></td>
          <td><input value="2"></td>
          <td><select><option="2" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="2a" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><img id="img2"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="row1">
          <td><button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button></td>
          <td><input value="1"></td>
          <td><select><option="1" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="1a" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><img id="img1"></td>
       </tr>
      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="SAVE"></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish - The values of the inputs should swap except for the tr. Notices the tr ids remain the same but form values are swapped:

Is there a way to achieve this in pure javascript, vanilla JS, or jquery. It will even be even better if this can be done with .html() instead of .val()

```
<form id="menuitems">
    <table class="toolbaritems">
       <tbody class="sortable">
       <tr id="row1">
          <td><button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button></td>
          <td><input value="2"></td>
          <td><select><option="2" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="2a" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><img id="img2"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="row2">
          <td><button class="up_arrow">UP</button></td>
          <td><input value="1"></td>
          <td><select><option="1" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="1a" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><img id="img1"></td>
       </tr>
      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="SAVE"></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get much assistance unless you reword the question. What are you saying is not working? What should the behavior be instead? Or, try looking at the "Related" topics to the right ==>

Comment: I just commented out this line from your script and it is working ok for the code above.    //  data.push(cells[i].innerHTML = target.nextSibling.cells[i].innerHTML);   Do check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took awhile to get back to this. I am submitting this as another answer so that you can compare the two solutions. They are quite similar, and you may find it useful to compare the changes.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/nq4rwe6r/1/)</kbd>

```
var tbl = $('table'),new_ndx,topRow,trStuff,botRow,brStuff;
$(document).on('click','button',function() {
    var dir = $(this).attr('class');
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var ndx = row.index();
    //row.remove();
    if (dir=='up_arrow'){
        new_ndx = ndx-1;
        topRow = tbl.find('tr').eq(new_ndx);
        trStuff = topRow.html();
        botRow = tbl.find('tr').eq(ndx);
        brStuff = botRow.html();
        topRow.html(brStuff);
        botRow.html(trStuff);
    } else {
        new_ndx = ndx++;
        topRow = tbl.find('tr').eq(new_ndx);
        trStuff = topRow.html();
        botRow = tbl.find('tr').eq(ndx);
        brStuff = botRow.html();
        topRow.html(brStuff);
        botRow.html(trStuff);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted from the very beginning I had to switch it to values to make the example easier to understand.

Comment: Happy to help. Note how `.html()` is used first to copy (and, later, to overwrite) the html inside the `<tr>`. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".up_arrow,.down_arrow").click(function() {
        var row = $(this).parents("tr");
        if ($(this).is(".up_arrow")) {
            alert("Inner Html Of Previous Row : " + row.prev().html());
        } else {
            alert("Inner Html Of Next Row : " + row.next().html());
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table tr:first-child .up_arrow,
table tr:last-child .down_arrow {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="1">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="2">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="3">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="4">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="5">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I need the innerHTML of the td

Comment: So you need only data.
You do not need to swap the whole row.

Am I right ?

Comment: Yes I need the data. What you gave me, I already have in my code on the server but yes I need the data or the innerHTML. Thanks

Comment: I updated the code to what I have now. I need the current row data to swap with previous row data

Comment: My code currently swaps the previous row with the current row. The input values belong to a menu so it allows users to reorder their menu items. The database only accepts the input values so the only way that makes sense to me is to swap the current input value with the previous input value but its not working out for me

Comment: But it was doing in my previous code that swaps the value of previous row.

Comment: Your previous code removes the first button, the buttons have to stay the same but none the less, the innerHTML in row1 doesnt swap with the innerHTML in row2

Comment: It swaps the rows.Up button on first row and Down button on last row does not make any sense.

Comment: copy my code and try running it, the rows only swap. I need the values of the inputs to swap.. I don't know if you can switch this to a chat but it would be easier to show you so row1 should have input value 2 and row 2 should have input value 1

Comment: Yes. it would be better if we talk through chatting.

Comment: cool I don't have enough reputation to start maybe you can start it

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".up_arrow,.down_arrow").click(function() {

        var objRow = $(this).parents("tr");

        var intCurrentInputValue = objRow.find("input").val();

        if ($(this).is(".up_arrow")) {
            var intPreviousInputValue = objRow.prev("tr").find("input").val();
            objRow.find("input").val(intPreviousInputValue);
            objRow.prev("tr").find("input").val(intCurrentInputValue);
        } else {
            var intNextInputValue = objRow.next("tr").find("input").val();
            objRow.find("input").val(intNextInputValue);
            objRow.next("tr").find("input").val(intCurrentInputValue);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table tr:first-child .up_arrow ,
table tr:last-child .down_arrow 
{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="1">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="2">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="3">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="4">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="5">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No it does not disappear the value of input it just inter changes the value of  one input to another input

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but your code is a bit all over the place.

[Here's a sample](https://jsfiddle.net/qoxn269u/) of a pretty basic 'up/down' table row thingy.

Try not to mix using jQuery and vanilla JS. If you're using jQuery, you shouldn't need to use `document.getElementsByClassName` (or anything similar) at all. Use the `$('.class')` selector.

```
$('table').on('click', '.up', function(){
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var $prevRow = $(this).parents('tr').prev('tr');
    $row.insertBefore($prevRow);
});
$('table').on('click', '.down', function(){
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var $prevRow = $(this).parents('tr').next('tr');
    $row.insertAfter($prevRow);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".up_arrow,.down_arrow").click(function(e) {

        var objCurrentRow = $(this).parents("tr");

        var objAnotherRow = objCurrentRow.next("tr");
        if ($(this).is(".up_arrow")) {
            var objAnotherRow = objCurrentRow.prev("tr");
        }

        var arrAllInputOfCurrentRow = objCurrentRow.find("input,select");
        var arrAllInputOfAnotherRow = objAnotherRow.find("input,select");

        $.each(arrAllInputOfCurrentRow, function(intIndex, objInput) {

            var mixTempValue = $(objInput).val();
            var $objAnotherInput = $(arrAllInputOfAnotherRow[intIndex]);
            $(objInput).val($objAnotherInput.val());
            if ($objAnotherInput.is('select')) {
                var objTempDropDown = $(objInput).html();
                $(objInput).html($objAnotherInput.html());
                $objAnotherInput.html(objTempDropDown);
            }
            $objAnotherInput.val(mixTempValue);

        });

    });
});
```

```css
table tr:first-child .up_arrow,
table tr:last-child .down_arrow {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="menuitems">
        <table class="toolbaritems">
            <tbody class="sortable">
                <tr id="row1">
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="up_arrow">UP</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="1a" selected>1a</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row2">
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="up_arrow">UP</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="2" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="2a" selected>2a</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row3">
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="up_arrow">UP</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="3" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="3" selected>3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="3a" selected>3a</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: I added images to the table in my example, would you be able to grab the img using .html() in your code?

Comment: I cannot understand what is the picture of array in your code

Comment: Cannot understand what do you want to say

Comment: You said you would be able to grab the img using .html(). Can you show me in your example

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".up_arrow,.down_arrow", function(e) {
    var $objCurrentRow = $(this).parents("tr");
    var strTempHtml = $objCurrentRow.html();
    var $objAnotherRow = $objCurrentRow.next("tr");
    if ($(this).is(".up_arrow")) {
        var $objAnotherRow = $objCurrentRow.prev("tr");
    }
    $objCurrentRow.html($objAnotherRow.html());
    $objAnotherRow.html(strTempHtml);
});
```

```css
table tr:first-child .up_arrow,
table tr:last-child .down_arrow {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="menuitems">
   <table class="toolbaritems">
      <tbody class="sortable">
         <tr id="row1">
            <td>
               <button type="button" class="up_arrow">UP</button>
            </td>
            <td>
               <button type="button" class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <select>
                  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <select>
                  <option value="1a" selected>1a</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif" id="img1" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="row2">
            <td>
               <button type="button" class="up_arrow">UP</button>
            </td>
            <td>
               <button type="button" class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" value="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <select>
                  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <select>
                  <option value="2a" selected>2a</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_opera.gif" id="img2" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="row3">
            <td>
               <button type="button" class="up_arrow">UP</button>
            </td>
            <td>
               <button type="button" class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" value="3" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <select>
                  <option value="3" selected>3</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <select>
                  <option value="3a" selected>3a</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_firefox.gif" id="img3" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ali beat me to the punch, but here's another way to do it:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nq4rwe6r/)</kbd>

```js
var tbl = $('table'),new_ndx;
$(document).on('click','button',function() {
 var dir = $(this).attr('class');
 var row = $(this).closest("tr");
 var ndx = row.index();
 row.remove();

 if (dir=='up_arrow'){
  new_ndx = ndx-1;
  tbl.find('tr').eq(new_ndx).before(row);
 }else{
  new_ndx = ndx++;
  tbl.find('tr').eq(new_ndx).after(row);
 }
});
```

```css
table tr:first-child .up_arrow,
table tr:last-child .down_arrow {visibility: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="1">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="2">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="3">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="4">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button>
         <button class="up_arrow">UP</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input value="5">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand. In the above example, when the row is moved, the input values are also moved. There is nothing else on the row, so really only the input values move, just like you desire. If this is not correct, then the example must be changed. ***Please provide an example that is closer to your real world situation.***